# How do I search for string within a string in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

How would I do the Haskell equivalent of this from Python?

```
>>> "this is a test".find("test")
10
```

Edit: basically I have some text, for example: "this is a test". Now I have a string that I'd like to find within that text, for example: "test". How can I find the character offset of "test" within "this is a test"?

Comment: There are a number of boyer moore implementations on Hackage, I suggest you look around.  If you aren't looking for something Boyer-Moore like then your question needs fleshing out.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I just need to find some text from a string.

Comment: Boyer-Moore is the algorithm typically taught in CS for finding the location of a substring (or even the existence of a substring) in less than `O(N*M)` time.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson It doesn't work on `String` because it requires random access for the skips. So it would work on `Data.Text` but not on `String`

Comment: For O(N) cost you can always pack a string - the algorithm's asymptotic don't change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want something high speed then you'll want to use `Text` (packed bytes) instead of `String` (linked lists of characters).  Text also has a, slightly hidden, indicies function for exactly this:

```
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> import Data.Text
Prelude Data.Text> import Data.Text.Internal.Search
Prelude Data.Text Data.Text.Internal.Search> indices "yep" "yep no yes yep"
[0,11]
```

Mirroring the naming of another answerer and providing some variants to give a single number, list of matching indices (possibly empty), and a maybe version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text.Internal.Search
import Data.Text

findString :: Text -> Text -> [Int]
findString = indices

findStringMaybe :: Text -> Text -> Maybe Int
findStringMaybe x str = case indices x str of
                         (idx:_) -> Just idx
                         _ -> Nothing

findStringWithNegOne :: Text -> Text -> Int
findStringWithNegOne x str = maybe (-1) id (findStringMaybe x str)
```

Comment: I wonder if there is an easy way to do this without "internal" routines. Is there some public function to do this (which might be implemented in terms of the internal one)?

Comment: Not that I saw. It would be a fine contribution to expose an efficient version.

Comment: If you need speed, there is also https://hackage.haskell.org/package/alfred-margaret for Text (and maybe https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stringsearch for ByteString)

Answer (score 7):

You could try using [`findIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndex) and [`isPrefixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

findString :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
findString search str = findIndex (isPrefixOf search) (tails str)
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> findString "test" "this is a test"
Just 10
*Main> findString "blah" "this is a test"
Nothing
```

Additionally, since `findIndex` is the type: `findIndex :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int`, It returns `Just Int` or `Nothing` here. If it returns `Nothing`, the sub string was not found, otherwise it returns `Just Int`. This is the Haskell approach, and is the most conventional return type here.

**Note:** If you really want to return `-1` instead, like pythons [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method, you can adjust the above function to this:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

findString :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
findString search str = fromMaybe (-1) $ findIndex (isPrefixOf search) (tails str)
```

Which uses [`fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) from `Data.Maybe` to convert `Nothing` to `-1`, and `Just x` to `x`.

Comment: I strongly discourage using `formJust` because `findString "no" "yes"
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing`.

Comment: Given that python's `find` method returns `-1` upon not finding the text, you could maybe use [`fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe): `fromMaybe -1 $ findIndex...` instead... Or just expose the `Maybe Int` and encourage the haskell-y approach. Also maybe worth mentioning this is `O(mn)`, whereas Python's may be different.

Comment: Returning -1 isn't even a great idea in Python, which could return `None` or raise an exception instead. That behavior is a leftover relic from C, best not duplicated in Haskell. Just return a `Maybe Int` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

```
findSubStrIdx :: String -> String -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
findSubStrIdx "" _ _ = Nothing
findSubStrIdx s target n
    | take (length target) s == target      = n
    | otherwise                             = findSubStrIdx (tail s) target (n + 1)
```

This approach is less abstract than some of the others, which can be a good or a bad thing depending on whether you're writing a library, what else it does, etc. As a new Haskeller, I find this approach easier to understand than some of the more abstract approaches. I don't believe it will raise any exceptions. To launch, pass in 0 for the integer, like this:

```
findSubStrIdx "hi, my name is Joe" "Joe" 0
```

and you should get a result like this:

```
Just 15
```

Now consider the case where the string you're looking for does not exist in the longer string:

```
findSubStrIdx "hi, my name is Joe" "Harry" 0
Nothing
```

If you want to use fromMaybe's and stuff like that, I suggest doing that in whatever calls this function; that way, you mitigate the risk of raising an unhandled exception. If you really want to do the C-style -1 thing, you can do that like this:

```
cStyleNegative1 :: Maybe Integer -> Integer
cStyleNegative1 Nothing = -1
cStyleNegative1 (Just x) = x
```

But, as others have stated, I suggest steering away from that practice.